# Как добавить строку при помощи JS в начало таблицы?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой добавления строки в таблицу. На данный момент имеется скрипт:

```
var mess = document.getElementById("messages");
var div = document.createElement('tr');
div.innerHTML = '<tr> ... </tr>';
mess.appendChild(div);
```

Пните, пожалуйста, в сторону куда читать, а если вам не лень, напишите как сделать:)
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: @Keltis, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: messages это table или tbody ? почему вы tr называете переменной div ? называйте element хотя-бы... в innerHTML tr, нельзя использовать тэг `<tr>` используйте `<td></td>`

Comment: это tbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например так:

```
var mess = document.getElementById("message");
var row = mess.insertRow(-1);
var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Some text message'));
```

пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8P3M8/)